# How can I import the distcp package in java?

Tags: java, hadoop, distcp

How can I import the distcp package in Java ? I tried `"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-distcp" % "2.7.1"` dependency and used import statement as follows

```
import org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.DistCp
```

But `DistCp` is not recognized.

I am trying to call distcp in my java hadoop code using tool runner but the import doesn't work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The simple thing you have to note down here is, the package 
 `org.apache.hadoop.tools.util` doesn't contains the distcp class.

Rather than that, the package
 `org.apache.hadoop.tools` itself contains the **DistCP** class.

To fix the issue, import as follows :

> import  org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp;

which will definitely recognized by your IDE, I believe.

For reference, refer this [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-distcp/2.7.1/org/apache/hadoop/tools/DistCp.java).